# Mobile Safari Address Bar

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, iphone

I am having a really weird issue with my address bar for the responsive version of my site, http://beta.life.edu.  Everything appears to be working properly, with the exception of the address bar, which basically never collapses when scrolling on the page. I've tested this on the following LIVE devices: iPhone 5C (iOS7), iPhone 6 (iOS 8), iPad Mini (iOS 7), iPad Mini w/ Retina (iOS 8), Google Nexus 5 (Lollipop), Google Nexus 7 (Lollipop), all with the same results.

on my `html` tag, I have the following css applied, which I **thought** triggered this behavior, but either I am wrong or I have another issue:

```
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

I've read through lots of forum posts about this, but any solution I've tried doesn't change anything, so something is obviously wrong with the scrolling in general on this site. The generally accepted practice is to add code that autoscrolls your site after page load, but this doesn't solve my problem, as the address bar never hides when scrolling.

Comment: Basically, you want to make the navigation bar disappear on scrolling ?

Comment: Correct. I must be crazy, but I thought that was default behavior

Comment: For the user's satisfaction, It should be visible when scrolling to provide flexible navigation. In bootstrap the default behavior is the navigation bar wont hide, unless you adjust the code to hide it which is not logical.

Comment: Okay, maybe I wasn't being clear. When I visit most sites on my iPhone, as soon as I scroll down the page, the address bar will collapse, so that the only thing see is the address. When on the site I mentioned above, this does not occur. So, I'm not trying to "hide" it so much as I'm wanting it to shrink or collapse.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by address bar ? The link bar ? or the navigation bar ?

Comment: The are at the very top of the screen with the url, the "reader" button (on iOS) and the refresh button (on ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm not entirely sure why this is the case, but on my `body` tag I have the `overflow-x: hidden` declaration. I moved it from this to my site wrapper class and everything is fixed. Thanks for the effort, @abdelrahman-wahdan

Answer (score 1):

Just add Javasript code:

```
    // When ready...
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    // Set a timeout...
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Hide the address bar!
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

The window.scrollTo method is the key to hiding the address bar.  The wrapping setTimeout function is required by the iPhone to properly hide the address bar -- not using setTimeout will cause problems.

**Bonus: META Tag for Bookmarked Sites**

If a user has added your web application to their springboard, the following meta tag can remove the top bar from the browser:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

And that's all!  The address bar is hidden until the user swipes down near the top bar of the application.

Source: http://davidwalsh.name/hide-address-bar

Comment: unfortunately, as noted in my original post, this actually doesn't solve my problem. There is something on my site that is preventing default behavior. Please see these two screenshots to illustrate what I am saying. http://beta.life.edu/life.png and http://beta.life.edu/overflow.png As you can see in the 2nd screenshot, the address bar collapses when scrolling. This does not happen on the Life site, as shown in the 1st screenshot. I have built several other sites where this behavior occurred by default.